# Unhook hooked cloth?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm dragging two corners of a piece of cloth by two hooks during a cloth simulation. I'm wondering if there is a way to release the hooks at a certain point and the have the cloth simulation continue running.
Thanks!

[image]

edit:
I'm looking to animate the hooks moving toward the conveyor and then release the hooks so the cloth continues moving along the conveyor by physics. The conveyor and cloth parts work fine, I just can't figure out a way to release the hooks.

edit: The suggested link above looks very promising to solving my issue. I'll report back after diving in.